# Creating a list of child objects (Transform child out of bounds)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an empty gameObject **Path** which has 10 subobjects (nodes) which an enemy will follow. In the Start method of my enemy gameObjects, I want to loop through them, to create a List, which I later can use to find the closest path node.

However when I use this code I get an **Transform child out of bounds** exception after adding three objects to it. What am I doing wrong here?

By the way, is there any point in making this list, or should I just loop through the actual gameObjects when I later use my GetClosestObject method which uses a list of gameObjects as a parameter?

```
private List<Transform> currentPathNodes = new List<Transform>();

void Start () {
    pathGO = GameObject.Find("Path");
    int childCount = pathGO.transform.childCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        print("Adding " + i + " of " + childCount);
        currentPathNodes.Add(transform.GetChild(i));
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
Adding 0 of 10
Adding 1 of 10
Adding 2 of 10
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds (Refering to currentPathNodes.Add)
```

Comment: do you have any method that return all child's ? Instead of `GetChild` ?

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir Yes but it returns array which creates garbage. It's better to use `GetChild` in this case and Lestat's answer describes the problem in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this:

```
currentPathNodes.Add(transform.GetChild(i));
```

to this:

```
currentPathNodes.Add(pathGO.transform.GetChild(i));
```

you are adding the children of the gameobject containing the script, not the pathGO children.